# How do I get Instagram Media of a user? Instagram Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

This has been such a frustrating struggle, but how would I be able to pull in media of an IG user that I already have authenticated?

- Instagram_basic permissions have been granted
- Business profile has been verified

**Graph API Explorer**:
[image]

I don't even know how to properly start, this is what I have so far:

```
<?php

$page_id = get_page_id('home');

try {
    // Returns a `FacebookFacebookResponse` object
    $response = $fb->get(
        '/178**********933?fields=media',
        '{access-token}'
    );
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

?>
<div class="inner">
    <header>
        <h1 class="duo-title"><a href="">Instagram</a></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="feature-window">
        <article>
            <h1>
                <a href="">

                    <!-- Loop Instagram media -->
                    <img src="" width="190" />

                </a>
            </h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </article>
        <p class="section-link viewmore">
            <a href="">View More</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are already getting media - you’re just not asking for any particular fields of the media object yet, so you are just getting the IDs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media#metadata (If you want to ask for particular fields using the above request syntax, then also go read up on Field Expansion in the chapter on basic Graph API usage.)

Comment: Is the Facebook SDK for PHP required to pull in Instagram media? I'm getting tons of "Non found classes" - I just installed it using composer.

Comment: It is not _required_, you can make your API requests using _anything_ that is capable of making HTTP requests. // Did you require the autoloader script first of all? With that, it should find the files for all necessary classes automatically.

Comment: @misorude, so I've got the Facebook SDK for PHP working and it's all loaded using composer - Now i'm not getting any errors anymore - All I need to figure out now is how to loop through and display the ID's of the media.